# Combining form textfield values using php implode

Tags: php, forms, implode

I have 3 text fields and I want to pass the values after combining them using a hyphen.

```
<input type="text" name="val[]" />
<input type="text" name="val[]" />
<input type="text" name="val[]" />
```

Preferably help me with php implode option.

How do i retrieve it after submit ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sending the form, your values will be in `$_POST['val']` or `$_GET['val']` as an array, depending on the method of your form.

You can combine them simply by:

```
$hyphenated = implode("-", $_POST['val']); // or $_GET['val']
```

Comment: thanks. how do i change focus to next field once a field has max values

Answer (score 0):

*thanks. how do i change focus to next field once a field has max values*:

See if this works:

```
<input type="text" name="val[]" onkeyup='checkVals("field1", "field2");' id='field1'>
<input type="text" name="val[]" onkeyup='checkVals("field2", "field3");' id='field2'>
<input type="text" name="val[]" id='field3'>

<script>
function checkVals(this_field, next_field){
var fieldval = document.getElementById(this_field).value;
var fieldlen = fieldval.length;

 if(fieldlen > 10){ // you can change 10 to something else
 document.getElementById(next_field).focus();
 document.getElementById(next_field).select();
 }
}
</script>
```